# Optical Disk clone with logging

Tags: windows-7, optical-media, login

So, first question on the site, please be gentle.

The issue:
Have a client who needs to clone CDs/DVDs.  To do this, they want to have some logging capability to see who is cloning what and when.
This is for law enforcement, so they need to clone things that are used for evidence, and some of it is not exactly legal so they have to make sure their butts are covered.
I can get the hardware sorted (another DVD writer ain't hard to find) but I keep hitting a wall trying to find software they could use.

I wasn't able to find a piece of software that does this out-of-the-box aside from custom hardware that ties into a custom ecosystem, and this is a local PD with a limited budget. 
If that exists (preferably open-source and/or free, but a reasonable license fee is fine as well) I will gladly take that recommendation as the answer.
If there's a way to do this with Infrarecorder or something similar, that works as well.  Infrarecorder has the simplest UI I can find for cloning and I think will reduce the learning curve.

Failing those, if there's a way to create a simple(-ish) script that can take a username, password, one other field, and then compare it to a user account file or database and then log the whole thing in a .TXT file before launching a program, please let me know what my best options would be for a Windows 7 machine.  I know it's not a simple request, but would appreciate some community input because I'm drawing a blank on how to get this done.

If this would take custom development of more than a few hours, I'm fine with that answer as well.  I just wanted to ask before I tell them we need to run it a certain way because what they're asking for is a legitimate need.

Appreciate any help anyone could provide, and thank you for any time you can spare looking into this.